# A question about the common zeroes of a homogeneous polynomial and its partial derivatives

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, monomial-ideals

Let $K$ be a field, $\overline{K}$ an algebraic closure of $K$ and $F \in K[X,Y,Z]$ a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$. Let $F'_X, F'_Y, F'_Z$ denote the partial derivatives of $F$ and let $I=\langle F, F'_X, F'_Y, F'_Z \rangle$.

Let's suppose that there is an exponent $e$ such that $X^e, Y^e, Z^e \in I$.
What are the common zeroes of $F$ and its partial derivatives in $\overline{K}\times \overline{K} \times \overline{K}$?
I thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: This condition doesn't tell you anything interesting. For example, if $F=X+Y+Z$, then $F'_X=F'_Y=F'_Z=1$ and your condition is satisfied but there are no common zeroes. On the other hand, $X^n+Y^n+Z^n$ for $n>1$ gives $F'_X=nX^{n-1}$ and similarly for the other partials, and so $V(I)$ is the origin as long as $n\neq 0$ in $K$. You'll need to refine your question in order to get a good result - what were you hoping would be true?

Answer (score 2):

For an ideal $J \subseteq K[X,Y,Z]$, let $Z(J)$ denote the zero-set of $J$, i.e. $Z(J):=\{ x \in \overline{K}^3: f(x)=0 \forall f \in J\}$. Then for ideals $J_1, J_2$ such that $J_1 \subseteq J_2$, we clearly have $Z(J_2)\subseteq Z(J_1)$.
In our case, note that $J:=\langle X^e, Y^e, Z^e\rangle$ satisfies $Z(J)=\{(0,0,0)\}$ and $J\subseteq I$, so we get $Z(I) \subseteq \{(0,0,0)\}$.

As KReiser pointed out, both possibilities $Z(I) = \emptyset$ and $Z(I)=\{(0,0,0)\}$ do occur.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. The aim of the exercice is to prove that if $X^e, Y^e, Z^e \in I$, then $F, F'_X, F'_Y, F'_Z$ have no common zeros in $\mathbb{P}^2(\overline{K})$ (where $\overline{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$). I forgot to say that I was working on the ordinary projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ and that $K$ is supposed not algebraically closed.